# how to get data from Jquery Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I am using this function try to make a request to the server. I am wondering how could I get data sent by Jquery Ajax in Rails controller.

```
function addnote(){

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url:SERVER_URL+"api/addNotes/",

        data: {note_text: $('#note_text').val(), note_lat: $('#lat').val(), note_lng: $('#lng')},

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error=" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Here is my rails controller

```
def add_notes


    end
```

end

Comment: what's your routing? do you get errors? what's in SERVER_URL? what does firebug say when it reaches this line?

Comment: 64 questions asked and ~50% accepted? don't you like people helping you since you show them no respect?

Comment: I like it bro, I only accepted when I receive my answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In rails controller**

```
def add_notes
    note_text = params[:note_text]
    note_lat = params[:note_lat]
    note_lng = params[:note_lng]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You lost params[:note_add] -> you have only :note_text, :note_lat, :note_lng. Check your 'data:' string.